# Is there a way to get HttpServletRequest from HttpServletResponse on my jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, gatein

I want to know if there is a way to get the HttpServletRequest from the jsp implicit object response.Note: I don't want to use the jsp implicit object request I need the one inside the response. Thanks on advance.

Comment: Why do you think there is a different request in response?

Comment: Where do you have HttpServletRequest in response? I have none on HttpServletResponse.

Comment: @kzyk I think that there is a difference because the id is different and the data is different. On the browser before Submit the form the plain request has all the data, but once the form is submitted `gatein` request has no data and the same id as the response>request. I was thinking to get a hold of the response>request and set that data there.

Comment: @Michal When i debug my jsp i can see that inside implicit object response there is a request.

Comment: If you see the object in debugger why do not you simply use it? But be aware that if you do so the jsp page will not be portable. There is NO request on response interface (HttpServletResponse).

Comment: @Michal Yeah i dont see a way to use in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) but some how I can see on the debugger.

Comment: @acardoso - I cannot follow what you have written to kzyk. Maybe you try to re-formulate the question in a way that we see what would you like to achieve?

Comment: What do you do if you move your jsp into another container and there is no request inside the response?

Comment: Request is what comes in. Response is what you send out. How could there be a request in the response?  Doesn't even make sense.

Comment: And how could there possibly be *two*, different, requests at the same time? Your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I wish i could paste a screen shot of my variables here. But you guys are right. I am still confuse for that request. Thanks all.